# From a Jython class how to call parent method in Java class

Tags: jython

Using latest Jython 2.6 beta-1 I derive a custom class `MyGame` from an imported Java class `Game`, then I want to override the method `render()` in my sub class. Within that method I want to call the `render()` method of the parent (Java) class.

I tried three different versions of how to call this super method, but none work.

```
from com.badlogic.gdx import Game

class MyGame(Game):
    def render(self):
        # here I want to call super's render(), which takes no arguments;
        # but none of the following three options work.
        Game.render()        # error: expected 1 args; got 0
        Game.render(self)    # error: render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
        self.super__render() # error: render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The builtin [super](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#super) allows you to call the parent class render method.

```
from com.badlogic.gdx import Game

class MyGame(Game):
def render(self):
    super(Game, self).render()
```

Comment: Calling `super()` alone does not work, but what does work is calling either `super(MyGame)` or `super(MyGame, self)`. However, in both cases the `render()` function is not called, but a new instance of `MyGame` is created. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Sorry I misread the docs, i've corrected my answer to reflect that super(Type, object) returns a proxy object that you can then use to call the super class method

Comment: That doesn't work either, I tried that already before. The problem here seems to be a bug in Jython, so that this command calls `render()` of the `MyGame` class, not the method of the parent class `Game`. This results in a recursive call of the same method in `MyGame`, until too many recursive calls have happened, then of course there is an exception eventually...